# Do nonsteroidal anti-inflammatory drugs (NSAIDs) decrease or increase swelling during the acute phase of a tendon injury?

Tags: tendinopathy, swelling

I have read contradictory statements regarding whether nonsteroidal anti-inflammatory drugs (NSAIDs) decrease or increase swelling during the acute phase of a tendon injury.

E.g., http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/97217-treatment:

> The use of nonsteroidal anti-inflammatory drugs (NSAIDs) is somewhat controversial. [1, 17] Some physicians argue that the anti-inflammatory effects of NSAIDs are helpful in decreasing swelling, thereby increasing the speed of an individual's recovery. [14, 18, 19] Other authors believe that NSAID use during the acute injury phase may increase swelling by increasing the potential for bleeding via platelet inhibition. [17]

(all the cited reference are at least 13-year-old)

Do nonsteroidal anti-inflammatory drugs (NSAIDs) decrease or increase swelling during the acute phase of a tendon injury?

I am mostly interested in epicondylitis (epicondylopathy).

---

- 1 Plancher KD, Halbrecht J, Lourie GM. Medial and lateral epicondylitis in the athlete. Clin Sports Med. 1996 Apr. 15(2):283-305. [Medline].
- 14 Baskurt F, Ozcan A, Algun C. Comparison of effects of phonophoresis and iontophoresis of naproxen in the treatment of lateral epicondylitis. Clin Rehabil. 2003 Feb. 17(1):96-100. [Medline].
- 17 Stanley KL, Weaver JE. Pharmacologic management of pain and inflammation in athletes. Clin Sports Med. 1998 Apr. 17(2):375-92. [Medline].
- 18 Burnham R, Gregg R, Healy P, Steadward R. The effectiveness of topical diclofenac for lateral epicondylitis. Clin J Sport Med. 1998 Apr. 8(2):78-81. [Medline].
- 19 Labelle H, Guibert R. Efficacy of diclofenac in lateral epicondylitis of the elbow also treated with immobilization. The University of Montreal Orthopaedic Research Group. Arch Fam Med. 1997 May-Jun. 6(3):257-62. [Medline].

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 3):

A big difference here is due to the structures involved.  Mature tendons are composed of cartilage and contain a **very poor blood supply**.  They rely on localized synovial fluid for tissue perfusion and nutrition as opposed to simply a connecting blood vessel.

---

[image]

Epicondylitis (lateral or medial) is a **chronic from of inflammation** caused over time by repetitive micro-trauma (wear and tear) to the tendon, nerve and vessel in the related area.

---

**NSAIDS would help with any inflammation and pain resulting from this.**

---

Also in looking at that medscape article.  It seems some involved are not realizing your tendon not only very minimally bleeds (if at all), **it does not produce sufficient platelet rich plasma that is capable of healing these micro-traumas**.  This is why injections of exactly that - platelet-rich plasma (PRP) is used as a treatment to heal the damaged tissue.

---

This would be a debate in more vascularized tissues (where the injury is generally some type of acute trauma and bodies own healing process is  required).

---

See Here:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2505250/